# Laravel Cannot declare class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeader, because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel, symfony-components

I just took a project from a couple of months ago which was made in Laravel. This project also utilizes Laravel Voyager - the admin panel package.

After browsing to http://example.com/admin, I got this weird error which came out of nowhere and I'm also unsure how to debug it. It looks like this:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeader, because the name is already in use in /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/AcceptHeader.php on line 22

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeaderItem' not found in /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/AcceptHeader.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeader::Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\{closure}(Array) #1 /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/AcceptHeader.php(57): array_map(Object(Closure), Array) #2 /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php(1664): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeader::fromString('text/html,appli...') #3 /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.php(54): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request->getAcceptableContentTypes() #4 /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithContentTypes.php(44): Illuminate\Http\Request->wantsJson() #5 /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illumina in /c/Users/User/Code/example-website/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/AcceptHeader.php on line 61
```

This error is very expected and I've never seen it before in my project (or anywhere else for that matter).

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a sanity check, delete the `vendor` directory and then run `composer install` to re-fetch your dependencies and see if the error is resolved. If not, then attempt `composer update` to fetch the latest versions of your dependencies in which this issue may have been resolved.